# create a Chat bubble in UWP using polygon

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml

i am creating a chat application and would like to create the chat bubble in UWP using polygon and it look like this,
[image]

How can I make it behave like I want using polygon in XAML?

Comment: How are you currently creating the shape? ie: What is the xaml or C# code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it behave like I want using polygon in XAML?

This chat bubble you showed above may not be created by [`Polygon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.polygon), since the boundary is created by connecting a line from one point to the next, with the last point connected to the first point, but your shape contains arc.

You should be able to use [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path) which is a versatile Shape that you can use it to define an arbitrary geometry. More details please reference [Draw shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/drawing-shapes).

I created the above chat bubble by `Path`, and code as follows:

```
<Path
    Stroke="DarkGoldenRod"
    StrokeThickness="2"
    Data="M 50,50 A 20,20 90 0 1 60,40  L 230,40 A 20,20 90 0 1 240,50 V 100 L300,150 240,125 V180 A 20,20 90 0 1 230,190 H60 A 20,20 90 0 1 50,180 V50" />
```

You can update the path data as what you want. More details about the path data syntax please reference [Move and draw commands syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/move-draw-commands-syntax).

The result:

[image]

Comment: Why does it need to be a polygon?

Comment: @Ash polygon cannot create this shape.

Comment: ok thanks @SunteenWu-MSFT, then can i have pointing portion in polygon, no need of rectangle in polygon

Comment: @Ash, if you don't need the circle corner, it can be implemented by polygon.